# When there exists a lifting $\rho e^{i\theta}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Assume $f : \mathbb{T}^N \to \mathbb{C}$ is a complex  function defined on a torus. I wonder when can we write $f = \rho e^{i\theta}$ (this is called a lifting for $f$) for some real functions $\rho $ and $\theta$. **There is some conditions of $f$ that assures there is a lifting?**. For instance, if the function does not vanish ($f (x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{T}^N$), then is there a lifting?.

Thanks in advance. Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Since every complex number can be written as $\rho e^{i\theta}$ for some real $\rho,\theta$, you will have $f(x)=\rho e^{i\theta}$ for some real-valued $\rho,\theta$ depending on $x$.

Comment: I guess that $f$ is continuous and that you want $\rho$ and $\theta$ to be continuous too (otherwise, the answer is always yes). There is indeed a lift if $f$ does not vanish. This is an elementary result in algebraic topology : you could take a look at the theory of coverings.

Comment: Can you suggest a book or a web link where I can read about it. Thank you.

Comment: I am not interested in general theory of covering, just in this result: if f is 'good' function  such that does not vanish, then there is a 'good' lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy if you use the machinery of covering projections.

It is well-known that $\exp : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is a covering projection; see for example [How do I prove $e^z$ is a covering map using this fact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1045933) .

Then each map $f : X \to \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ defined on a simply connected $X$ has a lift. See for example Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology. Clearly $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible, thus simply connected.

**Update:**

The question was modified: Instead of $X = \mathbb R^n$ we consider $X = \mathbb T^n$. Then in general there is no lift. Take for example $n = 1$. Then $\mathbb T^n = S^1 \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Now let $f$ be the inclusion map. It does not have a lift.

See also [A path from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ can be expressed in "polar" form if and only if, the winding number of the normalized path is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4013229) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look as soon as I can to Hatcher's. Only one doubt (just to confirm): if $f$ does not vanish (and is smooth and periodic, which is my case), then it admits a lifting?. As far as i known, the fact that $f$ is smooth or periodic doesn't matter for a lifting to exists. Am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I am afraid that in my case I cannot use your result because my function $f$ is defined on a $n$-dimensional torus, but this is not simply connected. Do you know another result that fit in my setting?

Comment: @Senna If your given $f$ has domain the $n$-torus, $T$, then you can pre-compose with a covering map $q:\mathbb{R}^n \to \ T$, so that the theorem applies to $f \circ q$.  Maybe this will help?  The covering map $q$ should correspond to the periodicity you mention in your original post.

Comment: Well, if there is no lifting, this might be of help. Thanks Robert. What would be a posible function q? What do you mean by '$q$ should correspond to the periodicity' ?

Comment: @Senna Okay, replacing $\mathbb R^n$ by $\mathbb T^n$ changes everything. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think that is the concept I was looking for, the widing number. **Can you suggest me some reading?** And sorry, I should be more clear with the question (I just put that my function is periodic, but then I write $f:\mathbb{R} ^n\to\mathbb{C} $... I should have been more explicit.

Comment: @Senna You should consult any textbook dealing with covering projections and the fundamental group, for example Hatcher (which is freely available http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATplain.pdf). Once you know the covering projection $p :  \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = \exp(2\pi i t)$, you can define the winding number for any map $f : S^1 \to \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ as follows: Let $\bar f = f/\lvert f \rvert : S^1 \to S^1$ and $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb S^1, g(t) = \bar f(p(t))$. This path has a lift $\tilde g : [0,1] \to  \mathbb R$ and $\tilde g (1) - \tilde g(0)$ is the winding number

Comment: of $f$ around $0$. It is an integer independent of the choice of a lift. The are many questions in this forum dealing with the winding number. In complex analysis it is introduced by completely different methods (line integrals).